# Sorting letters within each cell in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have this data frame:

```
AB  DC
BA  WZ
DC  ZW
```

And I want to sort letters of each cell using pandas, like this:

```
AB CD
AB WZ
CD WZ
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x : ''.join(sorted(list(x))))
  col1 col2
0   AB   CD
1   AB   WZ
2   CD   WZ
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df.applymap(lambda x:  ''.join(sorted(x)))
```